# Include-like in python?

Tags: python, import, include

Is there any way of doing an include in python like in php?
*This is not like the import function*

I'm a beginner in python and am writing an Irc Bot.

Let me explain what i wanna do, this is the script so far

```
import socket

network = 'irc.irchighway.net'
port = 6667
nick = 'bot';
canal = '#channel'
irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
irc.connect ( ( network, port ) )
print irc.recv ( 4096 )
irc.send ( 'NICK '+nick+'\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'USER '+nick+' '+nick+' '+nick+' :Python IRC\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG nickserv : identify xxxxx\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'JOIN '+canal+'\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG '+canal+' :Im here\r\n' )
while True:
    data = irc.recv ( 4096 )
    if data.find ( 'PING' ) != -1:
        irc.send ( 'PONG ' + data.split() [ 1 ] + '\r\n' )    
    print data
```

What i want to do is put an include inside the while, and create another .py, something like this

bot.py

```
import socket

network = 'irc.irchighway.net'
port = 6667
nick = 'bot';
canal = '#channel'
irc = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
irc.connect ( ( network, port ) )
print irc.recv ( 4096 )
irc.send ( 'NICK '+nick+'\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'USER '+nick+' '+nick+' '+nick+' :Python IRC\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG nickserv : identify xxxxx\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'JOIN '+canal+'\r\n' )
irc.send ( 'PRIVMSG '+canal+' :Im here\r\n' )
while True:
    include('function.py')
```

functions.py

```
data = irc.recv ( 4096 )
if data.find ( 'PING' ) != -1:
    irc.send ( 'PONG ' + data.split() [ 1 ] + '\r\n' )    
print data
```

This way i can modify the function.py file and change how the bot behaves without having to stop the script, which means the bot will disconnect and reconnect to the irc server.

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: There's `exec` ... but ... yuck ...

Comment: You should write a function, import it and call where needed.

Comment: This is why objects, configuration files, and constructors/factories/builders for those objects that take the configuration files as arguments exist.  Or even, as @cha0site says, just straight functions.

Comment: I can't import a function, i've tried that, but seems to me that even tough the import in on a while, python only import it once, so if i modify the functions.py while bot.py is running it doesn't affect the code at all.

Comment: You can force a re-`import`, but that's missing the point entirely.  *Don't try to import the file as python*; have an external configuration file, in JSON or XML or something, read that in at the start of each loop, then use the values loaded from the config to run your operations.  Then you can just modify the config file while the program is running.

Comment: You can use import and have it reload the module on changes. Some webservers already do that.

Comment: Python was deliberately designed to discourage you from treating source code as dumb text. That was once a common idiom in PHP, TCL, and JS, to avoid limitations of those languages, but Python fixed those limitations, instead of encouraging things like `exec` and `import`. Eventually, the others did the same thing, but by that point, they had a ton of code (and coders, and tutorials) out there that still do things the old way. The first thing to learn when coming to Python is that Python is not PHP, and if you can't figure out how to do X, it usually means you're not supposed to do X.

Answer (score 1):

There is not, and there should not be.  That simple! 
If you think you have to generate code on the fly (hint: generally you don't), do it in a string in the file you are running, and compile it with "exec" - no need to write it as Python code in a text file and import it.

now, you could use the "reload" built-in  function to do what you want as you describe - 
But it is far away frombeing a clean design.

What you "can't do" really is to have another file to be pasted as text in the current file before compilation - like it happens in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this... But this is just for debugging, ok?

`bot.py`:

```
import socket
import helper

def main():
    network = 'irc.irchighway.net'
    port = 6667
    nick = 'bot';
    canal = '#channel'
    irc = socket.socket (socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    irc.connect ((network, port, ))
    print irc.recv(4096)
    irc.send ('NICK '+nick+'\r\n')
    irc.send ('USER '+nick+' '+nick+' '+nick+' :Python IRC\r\n')
    irc.send ('PRIVMSG nickserv : identify xxxxx\r\n')
    irc.send ('JOIN '+canal+'\r\n' )
    irc.send ('PRIVMSG '+canal+' :Im here\r\n')
    while True:
        reload(helper)
        helper.do_thing(irc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`helper.py`:

```
def do_thing(sock):
    data = sock.recv(4096)
    if 'PING' in data:
        irc.send ('PONG ' + data.split()[1] + '\r\n')    
    print data
```